# MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, mysqli options not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the following warning

> Warning: mysqli::options() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in ...

when using this code:

```
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 300);
```

I am trying to run a query that takes much more than 1 minute to be executed. So I want to increase the connection timeout. The connection is like this:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init( );
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 300);
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, 300);
if (!$mysqli->real_connect($GLOBALS['ipServer'], $GLOBALS['mysqlLogin'], $GLOBALS['mysqlPwd'], $GLOBALS['db'])) {
    die("Error connecting to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

It seems like mysqli options do not work. Any ideas?

Comment: the warning is pretty clear: check the value of `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`

Comment: Value `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` is a php definition.I've been checking this but it has no sense for me. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php

Comment: You probably get another notice prior to this about a constant-to-string conversion…?! The manual says *"(supported on Windows with TCP/IP since PHP 5.3.1):*…! (Though I'm unclear whether that means *only* Windows or Windows only since this version…)

Comment: server is working under PHP 6 version on Windows.

Comment: [PHP 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history), ey?

Comment: In php info appears: PHP Version 6.0.0-dev

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use an old experimental, never-released development version…?

Comment: php 6.0 does not exist. Anyway instead of using the CONSTANT `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`, use its corresponding integer value

Comment: @GiacomoM That will hardly help. If the constant doesn’t exist, then the library probably also won’t understand its integer value.

Comment: @deceze maybe you right, but I am not sure about that. the function `options` does exist, and it just needs an integer value as first parameter

Comment: The question is wich integer value corresponds to each CONSTANT?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable all PHP errors, as it seems that you may hit a notice, such as:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT – assumed "MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT"

Which would indicate that the constant is undefined (maybe your MySQLi extension doesn't support it), and PHP treats it as a string, containing `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`. So the warning you see is *normal*.

Try to dump all constants, using `get_defined_constants()`, to see what constants are defined. You may also try to use the integer value as available in the PHP manual (not a great suggestion, but along with the right comment, that would make sense).

But it boils down to whether your MySQLi extension supports it.